# SimpleDateFormat() not giving IllegalArgumentException on passing invalid date format

Tags: java, simpledateformat, illegalargumentexception

I passed `%%#@-01-01` as date format, but got no exception. Why?

```
SimpleDateFormat df = null;
df = new SimpleDateFormat("%%#@-01-01");
```

Comment: can you post your full code..?

Comment: What makes you think that pattern is invalid?

Comment: The exception thrower is not the SimpleDateFormat, when you try to parse a localdate or format a localdate it throws the error.

Comment: @Sercan: That is incorrect. Parsing a Date with OPs pattern works fine. Also, the constructor will throw an exception if the pattern is invalid.

Comment: @Keppil you're right, the constructor would throw an error, but why is that pattern valid?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting the javadoc for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> [...] unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote. **All other characters are not interpreted**; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting or matched against the input string during parsing.

The format string `%%#@-01-01` contains no letters, but there's no requirements that there must be at least one letter.

Proof that it works *(well, "works" is a relative concept here, given that it's pretty useless)*:

```
SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("%%#@-01-01");

Date date = fmt.parse("%%#@-01-01");
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(fmt.format(date));

try {
    fmt.parse("9999-01-01");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

*Output*

```
Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 EST 1970
%%#@-01-01
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "9999-01-01"
```

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you have provided (`%%#@-01-01`) is not invalid. Only letters need to be quoted, all other symbols are simply copied into the format string. From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) (emphasis mine):

> Date and time formats are specified by date and time pattern strings. Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z' and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single quote. **All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied into the output string during formatting or matched against the input string during parsing**.