# Why SimpleDateFormat accepts strings with no letters as valid date formats by design?

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32391406/111110) and it seemed counterintuitive for the SimpleDateFormat class design, because it goes like this:

> I will NOT raise an IllegalArgumentException is the date format you give me
>   has no letters. That means I will accept any kind of symbol garbage and
>   I will return it to you. If the date format has at least one letter I will
>   check if it is valid.

I would expect that SimpleDateFormat will raise an IllegalArgument exception anytime an invalid date format is passed to this class' constructor.

This is my test code:

```
try
{
   String s = new SimpleDateFormat("34343434").format(new Date());
   System.out.println(s);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // no exception here
}

try
{
   String s = new SimpleDateFormat("3434a3434").format(new Date());
   System.out.println(s);
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
   // Exception, yay!
}
```

Why did Oracle/Sun made this decision for SimpleDateFormat? It feels counterintuitive and too much error-prone.

Edit: Forgot to say: I came across this scenario because I have to validate date formats (not dates) entered by user.

**Edit2:** 
I think this question is more suited for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ because I wasn't clear enough it was actually a question about desing decisions rather than programming:

I wanted to know the reasons behind a function that behaves differently from what you would expect intuitively (let's think the case you are coding the functions for a library you want to sell).

As some comments point out: the reason could be not to add extra complexity to this function, and with the documentation or the manuals users will be able to avoid those scenarios where the behavior of the function will cause bugs in the aplications using it. Also, less complexity means shorter delivery time.

I would be happy is someone tells me if this questions is better for the programmers site, so it can be moved.

Comment: Well, I guess they did the same thing that happens for `String.format`. Formatting lets you add some values where you put placeholders, leaving all other characters untouched. So maybe they did the same thing for Date formatting too: You can have a string with a date format inside, it will replace placeholders with numbers and leave everything else untouched. However I think this is a good question for Sun/Oracle's developers...

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is obsolete anyway. And frankly, if one thinks passing only digits as argument to a SimpleDateFormat is a normal thing to do, maybe one deserves being screwed :-)

Comment: Of all the design decisions you could question about SimpleDateFormat, you pick this one? :)

Comment: "I will accept any kind of symbol garbage" *because* "I told you I would" (see javadoc: *"All other characters are not interpreted"*). Are you advocating that it should violate its own contract?

Comment: @Andreas I wanted to know why they made this design desicion from the beginning. Complexity seems to be a reason.

Comment: @Broken_Window Quite the opposite. Adding an *extra* rule to say that format string must contain at least one dynamic value (i.e. a letter) would be more complex. Sure, a format string without replacement values make little sense, but it's not *invalid*. As BackSlash alluded to above, it's similar to having a `printf("Hello")`, which should have replacement values (e.g. `%d`), otherwise why not use `print("Hello")`, but not having replacement values is valid.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is very lenient in many ways. More often than not it gives you a surprising result in a situation where you had expected it to object to an obvious error. It seems to me they designed it with an attempt to make the best out of whatever garbage you feed into it. I agree with you that it’s a very poor design and one of the reasons we should not use this class anymore. Look into [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) and friends instead.

Comment: I didn't know the class was deprecated, I knew about Java.TIme but I couldn't keep track of all the clases that they want to update with the new api. As long as Java.Time is something new, tons of tutorials use the old Date/DateFormat functions.

Comment: I don’t think `SimpleDateFormat` is *officially* deprecated, at least not yet. In any case I recommend avoiding it for new code. There are tutorials for the newer classes. Yes, there are some to choose from, this is one of the strong points. So make a (limited) effort to pick the right one for your purpose, it will pay back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would expect that SimpleDateFormat will raise an IllegalArgument exception anytime an invalid date format is passed to this class' constructor. [...]
>   Why did Oracle/Sun made this decision for SimpleDateFormat? It feels counterintuitive and too much error-prone.

You seem to be missing the point.  A `SimpleDateFormat` format string without any letters is perfectly valid.  Its implications are [well documented](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> Within date and time pattern strings, unquoted letters from 'A' to 'Z'
>   and from 'a' to 'z' are interpreted as pattern letters representing
>   the components of a date or time string. Text can be quoted using
>   single quotes (') to avoid interpretation. "''" represents a single
>   quote. All other characters are not interpreted; they're simply copied
>   into the output string during formatting or matched against the input
>   string during parsing.

If there are no letters, no problem.  All the symbols are just copied through.  Why should there be a special case for that?  Special cases make code more brittle and harder to maintain.  It is not of much import that all possible behaviors be *useful*, but it is very valuable that they be *consistent*.

Comment: What I understood from the comments is that Sun made this decision to avoid more complexity for a class that may unlikely will be used for corner case scenarios where it can receive random symbols as date formats.

Comment: @Broken_Window You're assuming it was a deliberate decision. *Maybe* they couldn't even fathom that someone would write a date format string without letters, so it may not even have occurred to them to add rule (javadoc) and code to check for it. But why speculate about something like this that happened 20+ years ago? The rules are clear, and this is how they are.

Comment: @Andreas 20 years! I had no idea. I read about the new Java.Time api, but tons of tutorials use the old Date/DateFormat functions, and that's where I learned from. I can't keep track of all the changes and additions they are making to Java (I still have problems with the new streams stuff). So it seemed as a strange function behavior now, but maybe in 1997 it had sense.